# Powershell - only if statement executes despite input

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I'm trying to start my Powershell portfolio with and easy script that calculates Network ID or BroadcastID  depending on input from the user.  That being said, I can only get my if statement to run.  I am unsure what I am missing here.  I have tried searching this as I know I cannot be the only one to have this issue, but I am unable to find it.  Any education on my error would be appreciated as it seems like a basic flaw.

Thanks!

```
#prompt for IP and subnet mask
$ip = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your IP address"
$mask = Read-Host - Prompt "Enter your subnet mask"
[String]$UserDecision = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter N if you would like to calculate your Network ID or B if you would like to calculate your Broadcast address."
    
$splitmask=$mask.split(".")
    
$wildcard="$(255 - $splitmask[0]).$(255 - $splitmask[1]).$(255 - $splitmask[2]).$(255 - $splitmask[3])"
    
# ip and mask variable to ip addresses
    
$ip = [ipaddress] $ip
    
$mask = [ipaddress] $mask
    
#determine networkID
    
function CalculateNetID {

    $networkID = [ipaddress] ($ip.Address -band $mask.Address)
    
    #print NetworkID to console
    echo "The Network id is $($networkID.IPAddressToString)"
}  
    
function CalculateBroadcastID {
    
    $networkID = [ipaddress] ($ip.Address -band $mask.Address)

    #convert wildcard to IP addresses
    $wildcard= [ipaddress] $wildcard    
    
    $broadcast = [ipaddress] $($wildcard.Address -bor $NetworkID.Address)
    
    #print broadcast to console
    echo "The Broadcast id is $broadcast"
}
    
if ($UserDecision -eq "N" -or "n"){
    CalculateNetID
}    
elseif($UserDecision -eq "B" -or "b"){
    CalculateBroadcastID
}
else{
    echo "Please retry and enter the character associated with the ID you would like to calculate"
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I'd recommend using a `switch` statement in here for cleaner output. You also have to evaluate the `$UserDecision` variable again in your `if` condition. Probably best if you also use a `-Like "b*"` which is case insensitive or, you can just lowercase it using `.tolower()` method.

Comment: Thumbs up for @AbrahamZinala comment, I added the switch statement on edit.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala That is great tip.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```bash
$false -or 'n' # => True
```

As you can see, this is what's happening in your first `if` statement, the correct syntax for your condition should be:

```bash
if($UserDecision -eq "N" -or $UserDecision -eq "n") {
```

Same thing applies for the `elseif`.

Note that, PowerShell [comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2) are not case-sensitive by default, so the `-or` conditions could be just removed:

```bash
if($UserDecision -eq "n") {
```

You might also want to consider using a [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2) instead of chained [`if`, `elseif`, `else`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_if?view=powershell-7.3):

```bash
switch($UserDecision) {
    N { CalculateNetID }
    B { CalculateBroadcastID }
    Default {
        "Please retry and enter the character associated with the ID you would like to calculate"
    }
}
```

Comment: you may want to add a note that `-eq` is case _insensitive_ ... so there is no need to test for both the upper and lower case letters. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I think I already did, maybe I explained it wrong?

Comment: arg! [*blush*]  i managed to [somehow] misread your post. "never mind ..."

Comment: Perfect.  I really appreciate the help.  I realize Powershell is not case sensitive but I did not realize I could do it this way.  I appreciate it!

Comment: Yup, glad to help :)